# How to exclude a file for a compilation config?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a project that can either be built as an DLL or an EXE file, to be built as an .EXE file, a Main.cpp shall be included in the project.

I've set the Debug and Release configuration to build it as EXE file.

Now I'd like to set DebugDLL and ReleaseDLL configuration, (and other necessary adjustment), so that such Main.cpp will be excluded during compilation, and only generate DLL file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we don't in fact exclude source file because we don't include them but we exclude headers and include them.
 to exclude some code from source file consider using "conditional compilation"

```
#ifdef COMPILING_DLL
// ... dll code
#elif defined _CONSOLE
// .... console coe
#elif defined _WIN32
// ... win32 code
#endif
```

Comment: I don't understand, say there's two compilation configuration, Debug, and DebugDLL, how to set the macro?

Comment: if you write down sample of code you'll get surely efficient answers

Comment: Just note down what I did in case others run into it: 1. in Visual Studio -> Project Properties -> Comfiguration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor, I defined a preprocessor macro COMPILEEXE for Debug and Release configuration, but not define it in DebugDLL and ReleaseDLL configuration. 2. in the cpp file contains main(), use the '#ifdef COMPILEEXE ... #else ... #endif' to hide or show the main() function.